# How to intercept Form POST and forward to different URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure if this is possible, or if there's a simpler way of achieving my needs...

I have a login form that used to post back to our legacy system.

I have used jQuery to intercept this and post the form data back into the partially migrated system running on ASP.Net MVC - I now need to forward this call back to the legacy system with the original form data.

I have tried the following:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public void V6Login(FormCollection formData)
    {
        Server.Transfer("/bin/ussI.dll/do?cmd=Login", true);
    }
```

but I get the following error:

> No http handler was found for request type 'POST'

Comment: `Server.Transfer` is **not** a redirect. http://haacked.com/archive/2004/10/06/responseredirectverseservertransfer.aspx

Comment: this is true - I couldn't find any means within Redirect to pass Form Data to a URL. Server.Transfer seemed to have the ability, but it fails as indicated.

Comment: Fair enough. Do you have an HTTP handler for the `ussI.dll` defined in your config?

Comment: Ah - good point - it's configured separately in IIS, so of course ASP.Net won't know anything about it.

Comment: @Oded - if you point that out in an answer, I will accept - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that you have an HTTP handler for the `ussI.dll` defined in your config for ASP.NET to know about it.